# a:avLst values for arrow shape ooxl

Tags: xml, powerpoint, openxml

I'm working in a project in which we are creating shapes. Imagine that we are translating form an X tool where you can create shapes similarly than PP, and then you can export from that tool to a pptx file.

So far, we are creating really similar shapes. Size, format, color, etc etc etc. The only problem I'm having is that for arrows shapes, the arrow head is not completely exactly. So, I need to "play" with the a:avLst values. So, form the tool I can know the head altitude, and I need to translate that to the appropriate:

```
<a:gd name="adj1" fmla="val ??????"/>
<a:gd name="adj2" fmla="val ??????"/>
```

Do anyone know how to calculate those ????? values?
I know that adj1 is for arrow width and adj2 is for the "head altitude". And I also know that you need to set both (although for me adj2 is the important one).

So, summarizing, suppose that I want to create a down arrow with a 1" head.
Which

```
<a:gd name="adj1" fmla="val ??????"/>
<a:gd name="adj2" fmla="val ??????"/>
```

should I set?

I'll really appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there some reason you can't simply create the shape in PowerPoint and look at the XML to see what it's done?

Comment: Those values change according the shape sizes. So, there's a formula I need to find to calculate that. Actually, I need to know if is possible what I'm proposing: calculate the values to have a head of XX inches. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The logic for the arrowhead width seems to be:

LengthOfArrowhead = Adjustments(2) * WidthOfShape

So if the arrow shape is 1" (72 points) wide and Adjustments(2) = 1, then the arrowhead will be 1" long.  If Adjustments(2) = .5, then the arrowhead will be .5" and so on.

By length, I mean the distance from the point of the arrow to the opposite end of the arrowhead.  Width of arrowhead is controlled by the shape's width.

It can be a great deal simpler to work out the logic by poking at this stuff with VBA from w/in PowerPoint itself.  For example, you can paste this into a code module in the IDE and run it directly:

```
Sub Adj2()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        Debug.Print .Adjustments(1)
        Debug.Print .Adjustments(2)
        .Width = 1 * 72
        .Adjustments(2) = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Steve for your reply. Now: I suppose you are working with VBA. I'm working with Python using python-pptx library. So, we will suppose that I'm directly editing xml files. I need to know which value in XML file correspond to the 1 you are using for adj2 variable in VBA. Another possibility is that VBA just have those formulas inside and is easier to work with it. Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Yes, I'm working in VBA, Maxi.  Again, I'd get a feel for what you want by making changes either in PPT or in PPT via VBA, then look at the results in the saved PPTX files. For example, if adjustment(2) is set to .5, then in the xml, fmla="val 50000", where if it's set to 1 in PPT, fmla="val 100000".

Comment: Steve, again, thanks. I'll check the library to see if it has something of this implemented. If yes, maybe I'll be able to check what do you said. If not, I'll need to calculate the "big number". And that the complicated part. Bare in mind, that according the documentation, adj1 can have values from 0-100000. But adj2, that is what I need to use, can have values from 0-maxAdj2. :S. I'll continue trying. I need the math formula that says: ok... if you have a 3" arrow, and you want that arrowhead be 1", adj2 should be: XXX. :). Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: If you have a 3" arrow, Adjustments(2) will be .333 or so.  Adjustments(2)  = ArrowShape.Width / DesiredArrowheadLength (you'll just need to adjust also for the odd units in the XML)

Comment: Hi Steve. Many thanks for your continuous help. But, as I said, working with VBA is a completely different thing, because I'm totally sure that VBA has inside the same formulas the office has. Both are MS products. At xml level, this is not so simple. I'll continue researching this, using all the information you provided me. Thanks!

Comment: "because I'm totally sure that VBA has inside the same formulas the office has" No, not any more so than C, C++, C# etc. do. This stuff is all part of the PowerPoint object model, accessible to any language that automates PPT.